# Weird behavior of std::vector

Tags: visual-c++, stdvector, visual-c++-2008, release-mode, debug-mode

I have a class like this:

```
class OBJ{...};

class A
{
   public:
   vector<OBJ> v;
   A(int SZ){v.clear(); v.reserve(SZ);}
};

A *a = new A(123);
OBJ something;
a->v.push_back(something);
```

This is a simplified version of my code.
The problem is in debug mode it works perfect.
But in release mode it crashes at "push_back" line. (with all optimization flags OFF)
I debugged it in release mode and the problem is in the constructor of A.
the size of the vector is something really big with dummy values and when I clear it, it doesn't change...

Do you know why?

Thanks,

Comment: Since the vector stores OBJ instances directly (instead of pointers to OBJ), the push_back will copy-construct OBJ instances.  Is the copy-constructor for OBJ correctly implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I can guess - I would say that OBJ  probably does not have a correctly implemented copy constructor and/or assignment operator and destructor.

Comment: OBJ has constructor, destructor, copy constructor, default constructor.
My question is "Why the capacity of the vector is always something very big?" I used clear() and resize(0). didn't work..

Comment: @Nima The fact that it has these makes it even more likely that this is the problem. Post some real code.